# Quickbooks multi currency invoice

Tags: php, sdk, currency, quickbooks

Before raising question I had searched it over stackoverflow and google but could not find any reference.

I have been using the **keith palmar's Php SDK** from almost a year. I have **QB 2012 pro** version which is linked to my website using **webconnector**. I am pulling my invoices from my website(using **php sdk QBXML** provided to push into queue) and push it to QB using web connector. Everything work great.

Recently I have a scenario where I am allowing end user to pay invoices in different currency USD, CAD etc. That is,
a user can buy a product in USD currency and another product in CAD currency. This is not currency switch but actually buying a product in base currency CAD and USD. So the customer is same but his transaction behavior can be in CAD or USD.

Now, Since the invoice generated hold information about the currency too and I want to pass this currency information to invoice in QB when pulled using **QB web connector**. I have searched OSR but I could not find currency reference to be set as USD or CAD for a invoice(1 invoice with 1 currency). However I found some references when I googled that it is doable using

```
<CurrencyRef name="Canadian Dollar">CAD</CurrencyRef>
```

I tried it but it did not worked and **OSR** also does not have any such reference mentioned. **Please let me know if some one has faced similar scenario or know how to set currency ref in invoice XML**.

I have read comment(from QB PHP SDK guru) here in below link and that means it is doable but how as I verified receive payment add method as well as there also I could not find currency ref to set.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293 … 08#4316208

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QuickBooks for Windows sets the currency at the *customer* level. All invoices/payments for that customer use the currency the customer is set to.

You can not have a single customer with more than one currency, or with invoices or payments of more than a single currency.

If you look in the QuickBooks OSR, you'll see this as part of your `CustomerAdd` request:

```
<CurrencyRef> <!-- optional -->
<ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional -->
<FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional -->
</CurrencyRef>
```

You won't find this in `CustomerMod`, because QuickBooks does not allow you to change the currency a customer has assigned to it.

You do not set a currency on an invoice, because it just uses the currency from the customer.